# How can I have two signal in-phase?

Tags: pwm, synchronous

I have two signal 6Hz and 12Hz PWM; each signal generated from [AD9850 DDS module.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01J7XPWNU) Both have a voltage level of 5Vmax. How can I have them in phase. Example shown below.
I have been thinking about this, and I could not find a solution. If required, I can use 555 circuit instead of AD9850 to generate the same signal. I will not change the duty cycle; therefore, I believe it would simple be a 6Hz and 12Hz square wave with 50 percent duty cycle.

[image]n-

Comment: How are you generating the pwm?

Comment: As kartman says, it's important to understand where these pwm signals come from. Probably easy to do where the two PWMs are generated, relatively hard to do by modifying the existing ones.

Comment: Also:Is either of these signals the "defining" one, which the other follows?

Comment: @user263983 how would that preserve the **M** in PWM?

Comment: Define specs  required better

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 using two AD9850 DDS module, each outputs  outputs 6hz and 12Hz square wave with a 5Vmax output. I just want to see them inphase. Don't have a spec beside this.

Comment: @Kartman I have added extra information. I hope this helps.

Comment: Synced resets might work at that low f but no spec for PWM?

Comment: Remove the crystals from the boards and drive both DDS chips off of the same clock source.  That will cause their outputs to be synchronized.

Comment: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN-587.pdf

Comment: Don’t need any DDS https://tinyurl.com/yxtlgzpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DDS chip has dedicated reset lines. If you reset it at the same time, that aligns the points at which the first rising edges occur. You'll need to unsolder the oscillators from your boards – they don't make sense for you at all, seeing that your intent is *synchronized* outputs.

However, for a 12 kHz and 6 kHz PWM signal you don't need a DDS at all; in fact, the microcontroller you're probably using to interface these two DDS ICs can totally generate multiple PWMs without any external circuitry, and these can be software-synchronizable.

A lot (if not most) microcontrollers can easily be understood as multi-PWM generator units with a CPU attached to control that. A DDS can do cool stuff – generating a 12 kHz PWM with one is a pretty expensive and complicated way to achieve something simple.

Answer (score 0):

If they will always be a factor of 2 apart in frequency, and in phase, generate the slow one by dividing the fast one with a flipflop.

(Depending on the phase accuracy needed, you may need a compensating delay or re-clock the fast one to match the flipflop's delay)